# "list comprehension" in php.

Tags: code-challenge, php

PHP has closures, let's play around with them.

I have some arrays similar to, `$wannabelist = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`.

I want to do this: `compr( expression($params), $wannabelist, $wannabilist2 ...)`.

compr() should do the following:

1. Take all the possible combinations of elements of the arrays given as parameters;
2. Pass each of them to the expression passed as first parameter;
3. Yield the result.

A particularly satisfying function will:

1. Avoid changing the value of any variable;
2. Be elegant;
3. Contain an inordinate amount of nested parenthesis/brackets;
4. Avoid foreach() loops.

Comment: Note that closures were introduced in PHP 5.3.0 .

Comment: I wasn't implying it was breaking news ^^

Comment: After all the pessimists and nihilists, now we have wannabilists!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, a few neat things about list comprehensions, from a Haskell perspective:

- The list monad in Haskell is set up so any list comprehension can be transformed into do notation rather easily:

  ```
  > [(i,j) | i <- [1..3], j <- [1..3]]
  [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]
  > do {i <- [1..3]; j <- [1..3]; return (i,j)}
  [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]
  ```
- Haskell has a `sequence` function that takes a list of "actions" in a monad and returns a list of the results:

  ```
  > sequence [getLine, getLine, getLine]
  one
  two
  three
  ["one","two","three"]
  ```
- Consequently, using `sequence` with the list monad gives you combinations for free:

  ```
  > do {i <- [1..3]; j <- [1..3]; return [i,j]}
  [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
  > sequence [[1..3], [1..3]]
  [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
  ```

Hence, the `sequence` function is very similar to the `compr` function asked for.  It just needs to be wrapped and mapped a bit:

```
function compr()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $f = $args[0];
    $call_f = function($array) use ($f) {
        return call_user_func_array($f, $array);
    };
    return array_map($call_f, sequence(listMonad(), array_slice($args, 1)));
}
```

Now, without further ado, here is a nearly direct translation of the list monad and `sequence` function from Haskell to PHP:

```
# instance  Monad []  where
#     m >>= k          = concat (map k m)
#     return x         = [x]
#     fail s           = []
function listMonad()
{
    return (object) array(
        'bind'   => function($m, $k) {
            return call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map($k, $m));
        },
        'return' => function($x) { return array($x); },
        'fail'   => function($s) { return array(); }
    );
}

# sequence       :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a] 
# sequence       =  foldr mcons (return [])
#                     where mcons p q = p >>= \x -> q >>= \y -> return (x:y)
function sequence($monad, $list)
{
    $mcons =
        function($p, $q) use ($monad) {
            return call_user_func($monad->bind, $p,
                function($x) use ($monad, $q) {
                    return call_user_func($monad->bind, $q,
                        function($y) use ($monad, $x) {
                            return call_user_func($monad->return, cons($x, $y));});});};
    return foldr($mcons, call_user_func($monad->return, array()), $list);
}

# foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
# foldr f z []     =  z
# foldr f z (x:xs) =  f x (foldr f z xs)
function foldr($f, $z, $xs)
{
    if (empty($xs))
        return $z;
    return call_user_func($f, $xs[0], foldr($f, $z, array_slice($xs, 1)));
}

function cons($x, $xs)
{
    return array_merge(array($x), $xs);
}
```

I believe this meets all four of your criteria, especially the "inordinate amount of nested parenthesis/brackets" part.

Test code:

```
function printList($show, $list)
{
    echo showList($show, $list) . "\n";
}

function showList($show, $list)
{
    $str = "[";
    foreach($list as $x) {
        if ($str !== "[")
            $str .= ",";
        $str .= call_user_func($show, $x);
    }
    return $str . "]";
}

# Count in binary
printList('strval',
    compr(function($a, $b, $c, $d) {
        return "$a$b$c$d";
    }, array(0,1), array(0,1), array(0,1), array(0,1)));

# Combinations of items
printList(function($a) {return showList('strval', $a);},
    compr(function($a, $b, $c) {
        return array($a, $b, $c);
    }, array(1, 2), array(3, 4, 5), array(6, 7, 8, 9)));
```

Output:

```
[0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111]
[[1,3,6],[1,3,7],[1,3,8],[1,3,9],[1,4,6],[1,4,7],[1,4,8],[1,4,9],[1,5,6],[1,5,7],[1,5,8],[1,5,9],[2,3,6],[2,3,7],[2,3,8],[2,3,9],[2,4,6],[2,4,7],[2,4,8],[2,4,9],[2,5,6],[2,5,7],[2,5,8],[2,5,9]]
```

Comment: This is beautiful. You already had it or?

Comment: @cbrandolino: I hacked this up in a few hours.  However, it took me a long time to finally "get" how polymorphism is implemented in Haskell.  Namely, it eliminates type classes by turning contexts (e.g. `(Monad m) =>` or `(Show a) =>`) into parameters.  I did this manually with the `sequence` and `showList` functions.  Once type classes are gone, type information can be erased.  Philip Wadler describes this in his talk [Faith, Evolution, and Programming Languages](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2t9q-936yxw) .

Answer (score 3):

Implemented using simple modulus/division.

```
function compr() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $callback = array_shift($args);

    $total_length = array_product(array_map(function($arr) {
        return count($arr);
    }, $args));

    $return = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total_length; $i++) {
        $params = array();
        $_i = $i;
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($args); $j++) {
            $base = count($args[$j]);
            $params[] = $args[$j][$_i % $base];
            $_i /= $base;
        }
        $return [] = call_user_func_array($callback, $params);
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Test:

```
$array = compr(function($a, $b, $c) {
    return $a + $b + $c;
}, array(1, 2), array(3, 4, 5), array(6, 7, 8, 9));

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 12
    [5] => 13
    [6] => 11
    [7] => 12
    [8] => 12
    [9] => 13
    [10] => 13
    [11] => 14
    [12] => 12
    [13] => 13
    [14] => 13
    [15] => 14
    [16] => 14
    [17] => 15
    [18] => 13
    [19] => 14
    [20] => 14
    [21] => 15
    [22] => 15
    [23] => 16
)
```

Comment: Nice! Still a bit too many liar variables and loops, but it looks pretty lightweight - at least if compared with the implementation I had in mind.

Comment: It can definitely be improved. I haven't refactored a single line after first getting it to work yet. Will update when I do.